# How to make active link item bold when using asp.net Menu control

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

How to make active(selected) link item bold when using asp.net Menu control ?

Comment: Show us your markup and CSS so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the styles of the `Menu` control:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" DataSourceID="mySiteMap" runat="server" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="Table" 
        StaticSubMenuIndent="16px">
        <StaticSelectedStyle Font-Bold="True" />
    </asp:Menu>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 - View the HTML Source.

2 - Find the `class` name or `id` being used to signal an active element.

3 - Style the element appropriately using the selector found in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

If the link you are after to turn bold is a level

```
<asp:menu id="NavigationMenu" ..............>
    <levelmenuitemstyles>
      <asp:menuitemstyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" forecolor="Black"/>
    </levelmenuitemstyles>
    <levelselectedstyles>
    <asp:menuitemstyle BackColor="Cyan" forecolor="Gray"/>
      </levelselectedstyles>
    </levelmenuitemstyles>
</asp:menu>
```